# AKS with Static IP and Custom Cert / AKS Ingress issues

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

Well, for the last 2 days I battled this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/aks/static-ip
and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls

First of all I ensured that I had my aks k8s cluster upgraded to 1.11.5, so there is no question about having the static IP in a different resource group.

Overall, I could not get the static IP really working. With dynamic everything sounds fine, but I cannot add a A record for a dynamic IP.

I managed to deploy everything successfully, but any curl ip.. does not work. I did run exec -ti locally, and locally everything is fine.

Could someone please point me to a GitHub config or article that has this configuration running? As a disclaimer I know azure very  well, so well the service principal assignments are well done, etc. However, I am new, only a few months on k8s.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

I can share logs if needed but believe I did check everything from dns to ingress routes. I am worried that this doc is not good and I am just loosing my time.

Comment: you can use cname with dynamic ip, if you know azure very well you should know that. does your service work? did you create your ingress? what about controller?

Comment: I am using cname right now with cloud services, but for some technical & business reasons I will not be able to use it in k8s. I did create the ingress and the controller, both deployed fine without any error.

Comment: and because of that you choose to ignore other 3 questions i've asked?

Comment: sorry, it was not intentional. yes, did create the ingress and the controller. this is ingress: apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kdwk-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    # certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: dwk-at
          servicePort: 80

Comment: and for controller I used helm install stable/nginx-ingress with the override of externalIPs.

Comment: probably better to remove last to comments and edit them into the question. does your service work internally if you call service endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself this question, after quite a journey, for when I get older and I forget what I've done, and maybe my nephew will save some hours someday.

1. First, it's important:

In the values provided to nginx-ingress chart template, there are 2 annotations that are important:

service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group: "your IP's resource group"
externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"

Here are all the values documented: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/values.yaml

The chart can be deployed near your service's namespace, it should not be in kube-system (with my current knowledge I don't find a reason to have it in system).

2. Second, could be misleading

There is a delay of ~30+ seconds (in my case) from the moment when IP appeared in the kubectl get services --watch and till the moment curl -i IP was able to answer the call. So, if you have automation or health probes then ensure that you have 1 - 2 mins added to wait. Or maybe take better nodes, bare metal machines.

3. Look at GCE and DO for the same setup as might help:
   https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke
   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes
   The guys at DO, are good writes as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it seems that you are trying to override the `externalIPs` but use the default value of the helm chart for `controller.service.type` which is `LoadBalancer`. What you might want to do is to keep `controller.service.type` to `LoadBalancer` and set `controller.service.loadBalancerIP` with your static IP instead of overriding `externalIPs`.

Here some [documentation from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip).

Comment: Yes, I realized that and corrected it to use loadBalancerIP; but even using this I did not get it working until I got through the items that I mentioned. One more important item, that I forgot to add: using Public IP Basic SKU worked, but using Public IP Standard SKU did not. I am not sure if I need to set anything else here to get Standard working, but for now I go with Basic as I ran out of time.

Comment: One more comment for IPs' issue, this is the high level reason: Basic sku load balancer .. cannot reference Standard sku publicIP... and this is the Doc note: Note

Azure Load Balancer is available in two SKUs - Basic and Standard. For more information, see Azure load balancer SKU comparison. AKS currently supports the Basic SKU. If you wish to use the Standard SKU, you can use the upstream aks-engine.